# Need to add double quotes to SQL SERVER string values

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, parameter-passing, stuff

I have integer values that are being passed from a parameter that needed to be input as a string and padded so that they are 7 digits.  This will then be passed into another query.

```
   declare @t table(ctl_num int)
   insert into @t values(5675, 45464, 2323)

   declare @control_num varchar(500)

   set @control_num = (select stuff((select ',' + right('000' + cast(ctl_num as varchar),7)
                      from @t
                      FOR XML PATH('')),1, 1', ''))
```

This codes sets @control_num as ('0005675, 0045464, 0002323').  I need this to be passed as ("0005675", "0045464", "0002323").

I've looked at other examples on-line but I can't seem to get this to work.  Does anyone know how to get the double quotes around each value?

Comment: FYI, you should really check your DDL and DML statements *before* posting them. You define `@t` as a single column table variable, but then try to insert *three* columns into it, causing the statement to fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is some issue in setting `@control_num`.

Please try the following:

```
set @control_num = (select stuff((select ',"' + right('000' + cast(ctl_num as varchar),7) + '"'
                      from @t
                      FOR XML PATH('')),1, 1, ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
select string_agg(concat('"', right('000' + cast(ctl_num as varchar(255)), 7), '"', ',')
from @t;
```

`string_agg()` has been available since SQL Server 2017.  Also note that you should *always* include a length when referring to strings in SQL Server.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2012